# Complex power series is arctan function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm facing an exercise that I cannot seem to resolve...

Define the complex function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. Prove that for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|z|<1$, $tan(f(z))=z$.

The Taylor series of the real $arctan$ function is actually $f$ restricted to the reals, but even if it was a calculus problem I wouldn't know how to prove what is asked. Could someone please point out how to even approach it? I suppose I must differentiate the function, but I don't know how to deal with the power series in complex form.

Answer (score 1):

For $|z|<1$ let $g(z):=\tan(f(z))-z$. For real $x \in (-1,1)$ we know that $g(x)=0$. By the identity theorem we then get $g(z)=0$ for all complex $z$ with $|z|<1$.

Identity theorem: Let  $D$ be a region in $ \mathbb C$ and let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic on $D$. If $(z_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $D$ with $z_n \ne z_m$ for $n \ne m$ , $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n \in D$ and $f(z_n)=g(z_n)$ for all $n$, then $f=g$ on $D$.

Comment: To earn a upvote, maybe that you write the theorem you used and give a quick proof of it so that users know the theorem and your proof that used it.

Comment: I must admit that I need to read the identity theorem since I don't know it yet. However it seems that you have reduced the problem to showing that the statement in the question is true for real $x\in (-1,1)$ but the OP says that they can't prove that as well.

Comment: The OP says: The Taylor series of the real $\arctan$- function is actually $f$ restricted to the reals, Hence he know that $f(x)= \arctan(x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Then it follows that $tan(f(x))=x$ for  $x \in (0,1)$. Now apply the identity theorem (you may take $z_n=1/n$ for $n \ge 2$).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that theorem. It seems like analytic functions are weirder than I thought.